# How to store data in Vues store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I want to store the cart in Vuex store and I am doing it in this way in my Index component:

```js
storeCart: function (cookieValue) {
    apiHelper.getRequest(
        `/carts/${cookieValue}`,
        (response) => {
            this.$store.dispatch('storeCart', {
                cart: response.data,
            })
        }
    )
},
```

so in `mounted()` I am checking if there is a cookie, call the cart and with this way, even I refresh the page, I don't use cart items:

```js
mounted() {
    this.cartCookie = cookieHelper.getCookie(this.cartCookieName);
    this.cartCookieValue = cookieHelper.getCookieValue(this.cartCookie);
    if(this.cartCookie) {
        this.storeCart(this.cartCookieValue);
    }
},
```

But the problem is, after refreshing the page, I cannot add, delete or update the products from the cart.

And my action:

```js
export const storeCart = ({commit}, {cart}) => {
    commit('STORE_CART', {cart});
}
```

and my mutation:

```js
export const STORE_CART = (state, {cart}) => {
    state.cart = cart;
}
```

So what's wrong with my way of storing data?

Comment: "But the problem is, after refreshing the page, I cannot add, delete or update the products from the cart" - it's unknown why it's so. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "I cannot add, delete or update the products from the cart." Do you have functions for these actions?

Comment: And in the storeCart function, you can immediately use the mutation, why are you using another action for this?
And you can transfer storeCart to the store in action

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh, you will reset everything.

I didn't understand part are you pulling products from API or cart?

Anyway try to add created() hook and dispatch action or actions there

```
created(){
  store.dispatch('storeCart')
}
```

add also import for store at the top of script tag

```
import store from '../store'
```

Then in that `storeCart` action (you will need some kind of if statement for expamle:

```
if(payload)){
call API, mutation set cookies
}else{
mutation set cookies
}
```

add mutation `store.commit('setCookies')`.
In that mutation just get cookies you have saved before and save them to

```
store:{
cartCookie:{}, 
cartCookieValue:{}
}
```

Create getters for those two and call them in `computed:{}` props(you have cart getter example below).

So every time you create view(refresh page or change view and go back to "cart" view) you will call Vuex and get data you need.
And if you have `comutped:{...mapGetters['cart'] }` you can't have `data(){return{cart}}`

I hope it works and it help you.